# Using NetBeans for multiple programming languages

Tags: netbeans

I am looking for a cross platform RAD IDE with GUI building. NetBeans looks right (or am aI wrong?).

However, I may want to code somethings in C++ and some in Python.

It looks like both are supported, but I am not sure if I need to install two copies of NetBeans or if one can handle both programming languages.

Sorry it's such a st00pid n00b question - can anyone tell me quickly? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NetBeans is using PlugIns for handling multiple Languages, so you can code in Java, C++, Python, PHP, AJAX from within the same IDE (just open the other project and start coding).

Answer (score 2):

You can install just one copy of Netbeans and install the Python plugin. I use Netbeans for coding Java and Python.